# R CMD check warning in file.copy - missing DESCRIPTION file for unused package

Tags: r

I am writing a package and the R CMD check is throwing up the following errors:

```
* checking installed package size ... OK
Warning in file.copy(file.path(.Library, pkg, "DESCRIPTION"), pd) :
  problem copying C:\R\R-31~1.2\library\lattice\DESCRIPTION to C:\Users\NEASTW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2pKOkh\RLIBS_2be867c654c\lattice\DESCRIPTION: No such file or directory
```

And

```
* checking loading without being on the library search path ...Warning in file.copy(file.path(.Library, pkg, "DESCRIPTION"), pd) :
  problem copying C:\R\R-31~1.2\library\lattice\DESCRIPTION to C:\Users\NEASTW~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2pKOkh\RLIBS_2be8205547c5\lattice\DESCRIPTION: No such file or directory
 OK
```

The thing is, I am not using the `lattice` package anywhere within my package - to my knowledge. I have tried re-installing the `lattice` package to no avail. I think that the R CMD check is actually finishing ok and I don't have any `WARNING`s or `NOTE`s, so I am not sure whether this would pass CRAN's checks?

Comment: it seems you are using this line: 'file.copy(file.path(.Library, pkg, "DESCRIPTION"), pd)'  in your code somewhere. Is this true?

Comment: No :/ I don't have anything like that in my code anywhere.

Comment: it resembles [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Help-finding-source-of-warnings-td4701930.html) bug

Comment: I think that suggests your R installation is messed up - I'd recommend re-installing.

Comment: Right you are @hadley , I've re-installed R and no longer have the warning popping up. Could you please explain how you knew that was the issue so I know for next time?

Comment: Because I'd never seen the error before, and it's copying a package that should be included in every R instal.

Comment: I fear there is something more sinister happening here. I have had a repeat of the error, only this time it is the `MASS` package it is not happy with. It's the same two errors as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error came up as there was something wrong with my R installation. After re-installing it, the error was gone. Thanks goes to @hadley for helping with this issue.